# Combine several CSS classes into one

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

In a Vue project I want to combine a few css classes that I use on two elements in order to declutter my html. I was told I can do something like this with the cli, however i have no idea how.

```
.common-class {
  @apply .class1 .class2 ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create a `computed` property that returns those two classes combined:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    combineStyles() {
      return 'foo bar'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}

.bar {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p :class="combineStyles">foo bar</p>
</div>
```

No CSS preprocessor needed. However if you want to use some CSS preprocessor then [follow the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use LESS in you Vue files and use the [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) pseudo-class to merge the styles

```
<style lang="less">
.class1{

}
.class2{

}
.common-class {
  &:extend(.class1);
  &:extend(.class2);
}
</style>
```